# Practical Tcpdump examples?

Tags: tcpdump

I want to collect tcpdump examples, as many as possible!

E.g.: how to filter FTP passwords on eth0; OR how to filter HTTP 404 errors, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't do any filtering, but this example creates a handy continuous packet sniffer:

```
tcpdump -n -C 128 -W 100 -z /home/user/compress_logs.pl -i br0 -w /home/user/packetlogs/packetlog.pcap &
```

- `-n` don't do reverse lookup on IPs, don't convert port numbers to text descriptions, don't convert MAC addesses to names, etc..
- `-C 128` rotate capture files every 128,000,000 bytes
- `-W 100` limit the number of capture files being rotated (see `-C`) to 100
- `-z /home/user/compress_logs.pl` run script `compress_logs.pl` on each rotated capture file
- `-i br0` capture on interface `br0`
- `-w /home/user/packetlogs/packetlog.pcap` use file name `/home/user/packetlogs/packetlog.pcap`
- `&` this is parsed by bash; indicates that the command should be run in the background (asynchronously)

Put it in /etc/rc.local to run on boot. It captures all packets on interface `br0`, which could be two interfaces in-line as a tap or two interfaces hooked to a passive tap, or one interface hooked to a mirrored switch port (I've used all three in practice)

It writes ~128MB files and will automatically rotate up to 100 of them. When it captures 128MB of data, it will close the file, open a new one, and fork the specified command with the old filename as an argument - in this case a little Perl script that compresses the previous capture file for quicker transfer off the IDS server.

I use this when I have to monitor a connection for a long time (like a day or two) and need to go back and find an event that occurred at a specific time. The small files are much easier to handle in Wireshark than one huge pcap file.

Comment: this ones the best so far :)

Answer (score 4):

Capture only HTTP POST data:

```
tcpdump tcp[2:2] = 80 and \(tcp[20:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[24:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[28:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[32:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[36:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[40:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[44:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[48:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[52:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[56:4] = 1347375956 
or tcp[60:4] = 1347375956\)
```

A bit unwieldly but certainly useful. `tcp[2:2]` captures, starting from position 2 of the TCP header, 2 bytes (which are the port, port 80 being for HTTP traffic).

Then we want to compare the first 4 bytes of TCP data to 'POST'. The TCP header is minimum 20 (decimal) bytes, but since the TCP options are variable length, from 0 to 40 bytes (padded to a 32-bit boundary and starting at ), we have to test every 4 bytes from 20 to 60 (decimal). Finally, `1347375956` is the base10 big-endian binary representation of the ASCII text 'POST'. Use the values below for other HTTP types:

- GET `1195725856` (includes the space after 'GET' which is needed because we are comparing with 4 bytes)
- POST `1347375956`
- PUT `1347769376` (includes space)
- DELETE `1145392197` (just 'DELE', actually)

For other types, convert the 4 ASCII characters to hex (you must use 4 characters exactly), then treat the hex bytes as one number and convert it to decimal. For example, POST is `50 4f 53 54`. `504f5354` converted to decimal is `1347375956`.

Answer (score 1):

Capture everything to a file (so you can analyze it later with Wireshark or something):

```
sudo tcpdump -i en0 -s0 -w ~/capture.pcap
```

- `-i en0` capture on interface `en0`
- `-s0` use the whole packet (don't truncate -- snarf 0)
- `-w ~/capture.pcap` write to packet capture file `~/capture.pcap`

Answer (score 1):

Filter-making cheat sheet:

http://staff.washington.edu/dittrich/talks/core02/tools/tcpdump-filters.txt

Comment: Wireshark has provided a very useful tool for creating filters: https://www.wireshark.org/tools/string-cf.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor clients DNS requests on an OpenWRT router:

```
tcpdump -n -i br-lan dst port 53
```

- `-n` don't do reverse lookup on IPs, don't convert port numbers to text descriptions, don't convert MAC addesses to names, etc..
- `-i br-lan` capture on interface `br-lan`
- `dst port 53` filter destination port 53, the port for DNS service