# Practical Nmap examples?

Tags: linux, nmap

Like as there was: [Practical Tcpdump examples?](https://superuser.com/questions/286062/practical-tcpdump-examples)

I want to gather good nmap examples that can be usefull!

Comment: Disappointing this hasn't gotten more attention - `nmap` is a really nice tool, and great for more things then just [venurability scannig](http://www.securityfocus.com/news/4831).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

> [Secrets of Network Cartography](http://www.networkuptime.com/nmap/index.shtml):
>   A Comprehensive Guide to nmap
>   Written by James Messer

Is quite a good reference in itself.
It is available as PDF and on-line reference.

There are a few cheetsheets too,
[SBDTools](http://code.google.com/p/sbdtools/) has [Nmap5 Cheetsheet v1](http://sbdtools.googlecode.com/files/Nmap5%20cheatsheet%20eng%20v1.pdf) (pdf), among other things.

And, don't forget the **'[`nmap`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nmap)'** tag right here and across SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

Simply finding out what systems are up on your local net:

`nmap -sn "192.168.0.*"`

Use it sometimes to find out if a machine that I can't access locally (something has crashed, graphics driver errors, etc.) is available via SSH.

---

I also use it occasionally just to query what services I'm running. If I've found that I have enabled a service (such as `vsftpd`) and forgot to disable it after use, I can stop it.

---

See [man nmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) for other ideas.

Comment: The arguments are case sensative - the above example should read:

nmap -sN "192.168.0.*"

Comment: You should make a comment to say that you corrected it otherwise somebody particularly if there memory isn't good, will keep looking at the comment and what you wrote and trying to spot the difference.

Comment: @Joseph Redfern You misspelt sens_tive - it's with an i.

Comment: I'm sorry. Spelling isn't my strong point :)

Comment: @Joseph I'm doing a Ping scan, not a NULL scan.